# Tnsping, "Used parameter files" is empty

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, tnsnames, tns, tnsping

I am using Ruby API oci8 to connect to a remote Oracle DB, got ORA 12514.

My operating system is linux, the weird thing is when I do:

```
tnsping <hostname:port>
```

I get:

```
TNS Ping Utility for Linux: Version 10.2.0.2.0 Production on 22-JUL-2017 14:46:28

Copyright (c) 1997, 2005 Oracle Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:

Used HOSTNAME adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (CONNECTDATA = (SERVICE_NAME= my-orasvr.db)) (ADDRESS= (PROTOCOL =TCP)(HOST = 10.15.222.44)(PORT = 1521))) 
OK (0 msec)
```

The "Used parameter files" is empty, not sure whether it does matter.

Don't have any clue, any help is appreciate~!!

Comment: You might need to restart the network service of the oracle host.

Comment: Thanks for reply, you mean from the Oracle host side? or Client side? I am trying connecting other's Oracle database, not sure whether there has something I can change from client side...

Comment: restart the network service of the oracle host